# Flutter app making accounts and sending data between phones

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that is 70 percent complete and I want to make accounts that are able to send data between each other.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to get me started with this?  I am unsure of where to start.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to go with a server implementation. For example, using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as "server", you can set all the data you want to share at the Firebase Database or Firebase Firestore. And after that, from each device with the app installed, you can check the data shared through requests to the server (in this example, Firebase).

Comment: Thanks @Ademir Villena Zevallos!  I'm going to leave this question open to get some other opinions as well but that seems like what I will have to do.

Comment: Thanks again @Ademir Villena Zevallos!

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)